# Express breaking project

Tags: express, react-native

I am trying to use express but whenever I require it in my code it breaks my project.  This is what breaks it...

```
var express = require('express');
```

When I comment this out I can build my project but when I leave it in, I cannot compile.

This is the error message.

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `events` from `C:\Users\...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\express\node_modules\depd\index.js`: Module `events` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.
4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*`.
   at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:183:15)
   at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\Users...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
   at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
   at Object.resolve (C:\Users...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
   at C:\Users...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:399:31
   at Array.map ()
   at resolveDependencies (C:\Users...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:18)
   at C:\Users...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:269:33
   at Generator.next ()
   at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users...\Desktop\React\payme\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:87:24)

Comment: I'm just curious why you're trying to put express into a react-native project. You'd need an RN-aware events module, which even if it matches the events API, might still need its own import (e.g., react-native-events).

Comment: Does it matter that I am using a react-native project?  I'm new to react so I thought it would all be the same.

Comment: Yes, it matters. It's not all the same, that's why there's specific layouts, native interface packages, etc.